# Bootstrap Navbar does not hide li elements when collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got this code from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

When I resize it, it looks like this:

[image]

When collapsed it looks like this:

[image]

It's basically not hiding those li elements.

The **bootstrap.js** file is included at the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Got the jQuery library linked aswell?

Comment: Copying that code into a jsfiddle with jQuery 1.11.0, bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.css and bootstrap.min.js works perfectly.

Comment: Your code is fine. I guess you didn't link JQuery. Link it, it will work

Comment: I got Jquery included and it works, the irony is that if I include bootstrap over a CDN it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I could not solve the issue but I got a custom boostrap build.

I think that there is a dependency issues where some parts or rules are missing.
If I add a CDN link into my project everything works.

For future visitors, check the dependencies.